# How to remove pauses from rich-card BOT in Python?

Tags: python, botframework, adaptive-cards

Python using rich-cards sample BOT from github after every command demands "Type anything to see another card.". How can i change it to enable the commands to be given without interruption?
https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-python/tree/master/samples/06.using-cards

Comment: You need to post the actual relevant code, you can't expect people to sift through the whole repo for what you're talking about. And it's likely removing an `input()` statement.

Comment: Please clarify what it is that you are trying to do. Running the bot, we see that the bot gives uses choices to select from for the type of card they want to see, user selects their choice (like 1 for adaptive card), then shows the selected option with a 2nd message to "Type anything to see another card." What do you mean you want to "enable the commands to be given without interruption?" What is the interruption?